# How to get rid of picklist mis-alignment in the page layout

Tags: picklist, page-layout

I deployed a layout from one sandox to other sandbox. after the deployment, this strange this happened.
[image]

Please help me out .. I dont know how this happened.

Comment: Can you try to remove field from layout, save it and then restore back? Is it same behavior in another browsers ?

Comment: Is there a different (very long, up to 255 characters) picklist value in the org you have taken the photo of?